# PyQGIS - Start/Stop Editing with data Provider - Commiting changes

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-2.4

I want to edit a specific field for a `QgsVectorLayer`, within a QGIS application.

I am facing inconsistent results from my code, ie: changes are not alway commited. Please could someone point me to where it is wrong within this loop:

```
#vlayer is a QgsVectorLayer, imported from SQLITE DB
vlayer = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayer(layer)
caps = vlayer.dataProvider().capabilities()                
polygonGeom = QgsGeometry( rubberBand.asGeometry() ) 
#if vlayer is capable of edition
if caps & QgsVectorDataProvider.ChangeAttributeValues:

    vlayer.selectAll()

    for feature in vlayer.selectedFeatures():

        if feature.geometry() == None:
            continue

        if feature.geometry().intersects(polygonGeom):
            fid = feature.id()
            idx = vlayer.fieldNameIndex('some field')
            attr ={idx:'some value'}
            print fid,idx,attr
            vlayer.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues({fid:attr})

    vlayer.invertSelection()
```

Here is a post of my console showing that some features are selected and should be edited, but again, some are not properly updated to the underlying database.

```
2 16 {16: 4} 
12 16 {16: 4} 
13 16 {16: 4}
```

Comment: I made some changes to the code to follow explanation from the PyQgis dev. cookbook. section 4.2 Modification of a vector Layer without an editing buffer. Still unconsistent result. I can see that some features are selected from the loop criteria but not all of them are modified.

Comment: For a start, don't do this `vlayer.selectAll()`.  Just `for feature in vlayer.getFeatures()`

Comment: By doing this, I can still see the loop doing the job, but now, nothing is udpated at all (tried to add a `vlayer.updateFields()` without success also)

Comment: for info, here is the way I initially wrote the sqlite file: `QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer, layer.name(),"utf-8", None, "SQLite", False, None ,["SPATIALITE=YES",])` and the way I reloaded them to my application `vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(vlayerpath, tablename, "spatialite")`. And the output of `vlayer = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayer('some name')` gives me _'ogr'_

Comment: would this work if you did it on a shapefile? Is this issue only on a spatialite db?

Comment: could you look at this answer? http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/34868/5850

Comment: @vinayan I posted an answer that seems to solve my problem. Thanks for helping anyway. I didn't make clear in the initial post that I didn't used ogr data provider for the underlying database I wrote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found out why field attributes weren't properly updated.

I was related to the data provider, but it is a very specific case because I made myself in trouble not using  the 'ogr style' spatialite driver when writing my Spatialite files. Here is why it broke and how I repaired it:

1. I am performing local extract of a PG database. I decided to store each table in a Sqlite/spatialite database.
2. When writing, I used the `writeAsVectorFormat` method with **"special"** parameters to outpass some limitations that the QGIS API raise by using the "ogr style" spatialite driver. I already posted something here [working with spatialite](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/109411/pyqgis-working-with-spatialite)
   `QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer, layer.name(),"utf-8", None, "SQLite", False, None ,["SPATIALITE=YES",])` (I needed to implant Triggers that worked with geometry)

But later in my application, I reloaded all these SQLITE files using the **ogr library**, which seemed to work.

So, the solution was to import my SQLITE files, **using the actual spatialite data provider** which allowed me to get proper results from the code I posted initially:

```
uri = QgsDataSourceURI()

uri.setDatabase("path to my sqlite db")
schema = ''
table = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayer(layer).name()
geom_column = 'GEOMETRY'
uri.setDataSource(schema, table, geom_column)

vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), 'dummy', 'spatialite')
```

Comment: It is ok to mark this as answer if this solved your issue.

Comment: @vinayan yes of course